# Can a java listener catch an event triggered from within itself?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I need some help understanding a piece of code found in an application developed by my company. Because it is proprietary code I am not able to post the exact snippet but I will try to explain my problem.

The application is a java ee webapp, that has a listener implemented to catch a certain type of event. All normal so far...

Here's where it gets weird. The listener, after it catches the event it's looking for, triggers the same type of event from within itself, before finishing the rest of it's instructions.
It seems to be like calling a method from withing itself, only in this case it's a listener triggering the same event it is listening for.
It doesn't work, in this specific implementation, and that's a problem.

My question is: could this actually work?

I've tried to explain as best as I could but this is a strange piece of code. I tried to make a diagram of the way it is trying to work, maybe that will be more clear than my explanation. Image link below:

[image: Event listener runtime diagram]

Please help me understand if what this person was trying to do is actually achievable or just very bad design.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Neither your description nor the diagram make any clearer. Try starting again :)

Comment: What kind of diagram is that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds strange. It is normal for one event listener to "respond" by sending a separate event with the result - events are one way. Look carefully at the event identification, character for character, to ensure it really does send the same event it receives. Also, trying scrubbing out any company details and provide the code.